# Implementing Multicore Threading on this algorithm

Tags: python, multiprocess

I'm trying to find a way to make the following algorithm being processed on multiple cores, but I don't get on a good point. Using a locked iterator shared between multiple processes wouldn't be the most efficient way I think.

```
 def sortCharset(set):
   _set = ""
   for c in set:
     if c not in _set:
       _set += c
   set = _set
   del _set
   set = list(set)
   set.sort()
   return "".join(set)
 
 
 def stringForInt(num, set, length):
   setLen = len(set)
   string = ""
   string += set[num % setLen]
   for n in xrange(1,length):
     num //= setLen
     string += set[num % setLen]
   return string
 
 
 def bruteforce(set, length, raw = False):
   if raw is False:
     set = sortCharset(set)
 
   for n in xrange(len(set) ** length):
     yield stringForInt(n, set, length)
```

Short explanation:
 The code is used to create every possible combination
 from a set of chars, i.e. to hack a password.
 (Of course not my intention, just some Py-training. ;-)

**What is a good way to run this algorithm on multiple cores ?**

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I still don't get the StackExchange formatting.

Comment: Instead of `charset = sortCharset(charset)` just use `charset = sorted(set(charset))`. (There's no need for `del _set` because `_set` is local anyway.) Also, `not raw` is better than `raw is False`.

Comment: Thanks, the _sorted(.._ one is nice ! I've always an ear for suggestions on how to make code better.

Comment: Also, as a general principle, don't call a variable `set`, because `set` is a built in type, and replacing it just leads to confusion.

Comment: I think you might be looking for itertools.permutations - have a look at the docs, see if it's doing what you want. http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't really about naming style or how to get a sorted set of characters out of a string.

You might want to look into the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module. I'm pretty much a n00b w/r/t multi-core parallelism but got something working:

```
import multiprocessing, itertools

def stringForInt(args):
    num, charset, length = args ## hack hack hack
    setlen = len(charset)
    s = []
    s.append(charset[num % setlen])
    for n in xrange(1, length):
        num //= setlen
        s.append(charset[num % setlen])
    return ''.join(s)

def bruteforce(charset, length, mapper, raw=False):
    if not raw:
        charset = sorted(set(charset))
    return mapper(stringForInt, ((n,charset,length) for n in xrange(len(charset)**length)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time, sys
    if len(sys.argv) == 1 or sys.argv[1] == 'map':
        mapper = map
    else:
        p = multiprocessing.Pool()
        pfunc = {'pmap':p.map,
                 'imap':p.imap,
                 'imapu':p.imap_unordered}[sys.argv[1]]
        mapper = lambda f, i: pfunc(f, i, chunksize=5)
    o = bruteforce('abcdefghijk',6,mapper)
    if not isinstance(o, list):
        list(o)
```

The nature of the hack is that you need to use pickleable objects for the functions in `multiprocessing` and only functions that are defined at the top-level are can be pickled. (There would be other ways around this using `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Manager` but they aren't really worth going into for present purposes.)

Here's output for various runs:

```
$ for x in map pmap imap imapu ; do time python mp.py $x; done

real    0m9.351s
user    0m9.253s
sys     0m0.096s

real    0m10.523s
user    0m20.753s
sys     0m0.176s

real    0m4.081s
user    0m13.797s
sys     0m0.276s

real    0m4.215s
user    0m14.013s
sys     0m0.236s
```